# Graph API Error 2500

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

We are in the middle of upgrading to Auth 2.0 and have noticed a lot of errors in the Diagnostic page under Insights.  It shows "gr:" (which I know means the graph api) and error code 2500 with almost 1 million errors. Unfortunately FB hasn't got any errors documented so I'm hoping someone at FB can clarify the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." which means you're calling some API which requires access token without it.

If you do upgrading please note that some API calls now require access token like pageID/feed which previously it didn't.

hope this helps